# Hockey App Wpf Integration

Tags: wpf, hockeyapp

We have integrated the Hockey App in our wpf project as mentioned [here](https://support.hockeyapp.net/kb/client-integration-windows-and-windows-phone/hockeyapp-for-windows-wpf-apps).

For testing, I am throwing an exception in the client application and when I open the application next time, it shows a Yes/No message but even after selecting Yes I don't see any crash report on the portal. I check the namespace configured in the portal and it is same as the namespace of app.xaml.cs file. I have done manual configuration of the app in portal.

Comment: Please contact HockeyApp support with more details including a link to the app version on HockeyApp.